# Combining two random numbers in array PHP

Tags: php

How to combine $rand1 and $rand2 result.

```
$rand1 = mt_rand(1,1000); 
$rand2 = (mt_rand(1,1000)*1000);
```

I want possible result like 1, or 2, or 500, or 1000, or 2000, or 52000, or 950000; BUT NOT 5055, 10008 or 1000001.

I tried the code below but the result not as I expected; it never goes above 1000.

```
$rand1 = mt_rand(1,1000);  
$rand2 = (mt_rand(1,1000)*1000);

$arrRand = array($rand1, $rand2);  
$random_keys=array_rand($arrRand,2);

echo $arrRand[$random_keys[0]];
```

Comment: `array_rand` doesn't shuffle the keys, so `$random_keys[0]` will always return the first of the two values in the array. Use `shuffle($arrRand); echo $arrRand[0];` instead or only select one random key i.e. `$random_key=array_rand($arrRand); echo $arrRand[$random_key];`

Comment: I think there is a little mistake in question closing. As far as I understood OP wanted and wants to merge two arrays, and couldn't find a way. [This](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_merge.php) might help. Can't find a link to Stackoverflow answer right now though

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I don't think so. I think OP's question is why, given an array of 2 values, one < 1000 and one > 1000, their code always returns a value < 1000.

Comment: [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YNUDu)

Comment: @Nick, i need just one result number, not two.

Comment: @jzuhri both my suggestions will only give you one result - the demo was just so you could see both methods in operation.